# Updating a mysql db with php ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this **php** code that updates a row in my **MySQL** database, based on 3 variables sent with **ajax** but that returns a http **500 error**:

```
<?php
$dbname = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$dbhost = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to Connect to '$dbhost'");
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

$topparent = $_POST['name']; 
$column = $_POST['column']; 
$value = $_POST['value']; 

$sql = "UPDATE reloaded SET" . $column . " = '" .$value . "'WHERE top_parent = '" . $name ."';

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $link );
         if(! $retval ) {
            die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
         }
         echo "success\n";
         mysql_close($link);
?>
```

My **jquery** js is this. The variables get passed correctly (tried with alert):

```
function updatedb(a,b,c){
    $.ajax({
       url: "updatedb.php",
       type: 'POST',
       data: ({name:a,column:b,value:c}),
       success: function(msg) {
          alert('DB updated');
       }               
    });
};
```

Any idea why it returns an error? I have spent some time going over the code, trying different variations but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: In your success function, write `console.log(msg)`

Comment: (1) you have missing quote in `$sql`. (2) you have syntax issues in `$sql`, as you do not have spaces after `SET`. (3) you are wide open to sql injection. you should whitelist your columns and sanitize your data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: which version of PHP are you using?, mysql_* has been deprecated as of PHP 7

Comment: @Sean That post about injections is a bit complex for me, still a lot to learn. Would just adding an if statement checking against a fixed set of values be enough to protect the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PHP syntax error in the SQL query statement.

You have missed to end the `"` and hence the 500 error.

**The corrected code**:

```
$sql = "UPDATE reloaded SET " . $column . " = '" .$value . "' WHERE top_parent = '" . $name ."'";
```

**Edit**

Adding to that, there is no space after the `SET` keyword.

Fixing this will update your db properly.

Comment: there is another syntax issue, in addition to being wide open to sql injection

Comment: ah... yes I see now, it now successfully executes, even though it doesn't seem to update the db yet, but that's another issue.

Comment: @Sean Yes you are right, added the space after SET. which anyways will not throw the 500 error.

Comment: @RamC no, it would not cause the 500 error, but would impact the db update that the OP said wasn't happening in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852068/updating-a-mysql-db-with-php-ajax-request/47852092?noredirect=1#comment82668540_47852092)

Comment: yes sean, @cmplieger i've edited the answer, the db update should happen now.

Comment: I got it up and running. Also converted from MySQL to mysqli thanks to comments on initial post. Have to work on injection, although it's an internal app and not super important. Thanks for your help!